# Limits of a twice differentiable function.

Tags: limits

Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} xf(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xf''(x)=0$. Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xf'(x)=0$.

Comment: What have you tried? In general people on this website don't like it when people don't show their attempts, since it makes people feel like we're just doing your homework...

Comment: I'm sorry, I was able to solve the exercise. A student asked me and I found it funny, so I decided to share with other student in the website. (I'm a Phd student)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Taylor-Lagrange Formula for $b=x+1$ and $a=x$, we have

$$f(x+1)=f(x)+f^{\prime}(x)+\frac{1}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(c_x)$$
for some $c_x\in (x,x+1)$. We multiply by $x$:
$$xf(x+1)=xf(x)+xf^{\prime}(x)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{c_x}c_xf^{\prime\prime}(c_x)$$

Now if $x\to +\infty$, $c_x\to +\infty$, and $c_xf^{\prime\prime}(c_x)\to 0$. We have $\displaystyle \frac{x}{x+1}\leq \frac{x}{c_x}\leq 1$, hence $\displaystyle \frac{x}{c_x}\to 1$. So the last term $\to 0$ as $x\to+\infty$. As $xf(x)$ and $xf(x+1)$ $\to 0$ also, we get that $xf^{\prime}(x)\to 0$.